# Grails' BootStrap#init equivalent in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, grails, web-applications, spring-boot

I would like to populate some initial / sample records in my Spring Boot JPA MVC web application. In Grails I saw a sample, where such initialization was done in `grails-app/init/BootStrap` file, in `init` closure.

How to do the same in Spring Boot web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing special. Just create a class for the initialization and declare it as a spring bean. Declare your dependencies like repository, logger, transaction etc. as you would for a typical `spring bean`.

Spring has several approaches for declaring a method that will be called after bean creation like `postConstruct`, `afterPropertiesSet`, `init-method` etc. You can use any of those to kick off your initialization. For more on initialization callbacks http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean

Here is a nice blog with example https://coderwall.com/p/wfmxga/bootstrapping-data-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Bootstrap implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // YOUR CODE...
    }
}
```